# Symfony and Azure Distribution Bundle - assets in Azure

Tags: php, symfony, azure

I am trying to deploy an existing Symfony 2.1 application to Azure. For this I am using the [Azure Distribution Bundle](http://beberlei.github.com/AzureDistributionBundle/), and I am trying to deploy assets to Azure as documented [here](http://beberlei.github.com/AzureDistributionBundle/assets.html).

However, I am getting an error when doing windowsazure:package to create the package:

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 2 passed to WindowsAzure\DistributionBundle\Deployment\Assets\BlobStrategy::__construct() must be an instance of WindowsAzure\Blob\BlobRestProxy, none given, called in C:\IGPR\igpr\app\cache\azure\appAzureDebugProjectContainer.php on line 2361 and defined in C:\IGPR\igpr\vendor\beberlei\azure-distribution-bundle\WindowsAzure\DistributionBundle\Deployment\Assets\BlobStrategy.php line 35

Here is the relevant section of my config.yml:

```
windows_azure_distribution:
...
    services:
        blob:
            default: UseDevelopmentStorage=true
            azureprod: DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=myaccountname;AccountKey=MyVeryLongAccOUntKeY==
    assets:
        type: blob
        connection_name: azureprod
```

Any ideas? Seems that the Blob proxy cannot be created. I get the same error if I try to use the local development storage.

The bundle is installed via Composer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this was a bug in the Azure Distribution Bundle, which the maintainer [has now fixed](https://github.com/beberlei/AzureDistributionBundle/commit/960916446fe9779685e6b280d917bf1cf0accd81).